# PHP displaying utf-8 from ISO-8859-1

Tags: php, utf-8, iso-8859-1

how can i properly display the $string as it would be displayed in $string_result

```
$string = "&#195;&#x20ac;";
$string = html_entity_decode($string); //output as Ã€
$string_result = "Ã€";

echo "<br>This: " .  $string;
echo "<br>Should become: " . ($string_result);
```

output is

```
This: Ã€
Should become: À
```

If i hardcoded the Ã€ in the code ($string_result), the display is correct, but if it was assigned in variable ($string), its not displaying the same as $string_result.

The weird thing is when i do this :

```
echo htmlentities($string);
echo htmlentities($string_result);
```

the output is like this

```
&Atilde;&euro;
&Agrave;
```

Comment: Something is really messed up here! Those are not the HTML entities for the character "À". What you have here is that you're decoding the HTML entities to one encoding, but then you want to interpret that as another encoding in which it happens to converge to the character you expect. Why do you have these messed up HTML entities in the first place? This is something you need to fix at the source. If you want an "À", you need the HTML entity `&Agrave;`, not A-tilde and the Euro sign.

Comment: As deceze says, if your input is `&#195;&#x20ac;`, that's already completely garbled. What's *probably* happened is that the single Unicode codepoint U+00C0 has been expressed in UTF-8 as the byte sequence 0xC3 0x80; that byte sequence has been read back as Windows code page 1252 (not ISO 8859-1), where it would represent `Ã€`, and *then* HTML-encoded, using a Unicode-aware encoder which turned the euro symbol into `&#x20ac;`. If that's consistently what happened with your input, you *might* be able to reverse engineer the original text, but it could well be unrecoverable garbage.

Comment: here's another observation, in firefox browser, the $string_result is empty so i think it only displays well in chrome

Comment: @butching I promise you this has absolutely nothing to do with browser display. You have mangled data, and need to either fix that data at source, or work out exactly what steps it went through to become mangled, and carefully reverse each of those steps, hoping that none of them have resulted in data loss (e.g. removal of byte sequences which are invalid / non-printable in one of the encodings involved).

Answer (score 1):

Add the header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

at the beginning of your code.

Comment: it doesnt matter if you put header or not, its still wrong

Comment: Are you sure the decoded entity should look like what you expect?

Comment: @m.nachury See the comments deceze and I have added under the question. The data is more mangled than the original question implied, so this is definitely not a problem of browser display.